# Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 rspec testing

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have an rspec/selenium/capybara suite that has been working flawlessly for months. Now suddenly I am getting a whole host of errors:

```
Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

I am testing an actual website, not a local instance so I don't know why 127.0.0.1 is showing up at all. I know there are a number of other questions similar to this on here, but I have yet to find one that addresses my issue.

Not sure what other information to include...

Comment: "Not sure what other information to include... " Some code would be nice. :)

Comment: You're running a selenium test suite on your local machine right? That runs a instance of your app on your machine so that selenium can connect to it. It appears to me that some other process is using port 9515, so try to find what process if using that port.

Comment: first thing I would check if your browser version is compatible with your selenium version.

Answer (score 1):

Port 9515 is the default port for `chromedriver`, so the connection attempt to `127.0.0.1:9515` is selenium attempting to connect to chromedriver in order to control the browser (Chrome) - The error would tend to indicate that chromedriver isn't starting up correctly.  Check you have the latest version of `chromedriver` installed (or at least one that is compatible with the version of Chrome you're using') and also update selenium-webdriver. If using the `chromedriver-helper` gem you need to do `bundle exec chromedriver -v` when checking which version you're actually using since it installs a shim that can end up with you using a different version than it would appear if you just ran `chromedriver -v`

Comment: Geckodriver and chrome? Geckodriver can be used to drive the chrome browser?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Sorry, `meant chromedriver` - was working on some Capybara  workarounds for geckodriver deficiencies at the same time and typed the wrong thing - fixed

Comment: I'm getting the same issues with this error but it is happening mid test, not at the first step.  I've tried reverting back to an older version of chromedriver and updating selenium-webdriver.

Comment: @Tom Without details it's impossible to say - open a new question with the exact details of what you're using, a sample of the failing code, and what you've tried.